# Clear bound SmartTable textbox with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, pug, smart-table

I am using SmartTable with my Angular 1.2.x app. Specifically, I am following the pattern where a list of predicates drive the search process. A specific example of this is given on the project site [here](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#section-filter).

You can see from the example that when you select a predicate and perform a search, then select another predicate in the list, the textbox still contains the previous search criteria.

I am fairly new to AngularJS and I am trying, in an AngularJS way, to clear the search results on the change event of the predicate select box. My first thought was to push any type of DOM manipulation behind a directive. So I created one for resetting the search criteria call "tndResetSearch" . My syntax in jade seems quite messy...if there is a better way to organize this, I welcome the advice ;) :

```
select.form-control.tnd-reset-search(name="selectedPredicate", type="text" ng-model="selectedPredicate",
  ng-options="predicate.PredicateId as predicate.PredicateName for predicate in predicates",
  itemdata="predicate", options="#serviceLogSearchBox", resetsearch="resetSearch()")
```

`resetsearch="resetSearch()"` is bound to the isolate scope property of my directive.

The implementation of that is in the controller which simply clears the model from the `$scope` and repopulates the collection used by smart-table to populate the view:

```
$scope.resetSearch = function() {
  delete $scope.searchQuery;
  $scope.initCollection();
}

$scope.initCollection = function() {
  $scope.serviceLogCollection = '';
  $scope.serviceLogCollection = [].concat($scope.originalServiceLogCollection);
};
```

This gets executed just fine, but each time I change the predicate in the selectbox, the previous search criteria appear to be cached and appended to the current search criteria. So I end up with a subset of the previous search. I am not sure where the caching is taking place. There must be something in the `$scope` that the SmartTable search directive looks at prior to the next search. I will have to look at SmartTable next to see if I can track this down unless I am doing something completely wrong in my approach.

The `options="#serviceLogSearchBox"` in the `select` box above was another attempt by me to try to get a reference to the associated search box and clear it manually, but that had not effect at all.

Here is my first shot at the directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('tndResetSearch', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'CA',
        replace: false,
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            index: '=index',
            predicate: '=itemdata',
            resetSearch: '&resetsearch'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            var maxNukes=100, currentNuke=0, triggerKeyDown, nukeSearch;

            triggerKeyDown = function (element, keyCode) {
              var e = angular.element.Event('keydown');
              e.which = keyCode;
              element.trigger(e);
            };

            nukeSearch = function() {
                // Trigger keydown event for bound element that uses the stSearch directive???
                // This never actually does anything, It just loops forever.
                //
                // var target = angular.element(attrs.options);
                // while (target.val().length > 0 && currentNuke < maxNukes) {
                //    triggerKeyDown(target, 8); //backspace=8
                //    currentNuke++;
                //}
                // Call referenced function on isolate scope
                scope.resetSearch();
            };

            // Modify the DOM the first time the view renders with the first item selected
            if (parseInt(scope.index)===0) {
                nukeSearch();
            }

            elem.bind('change', function (evt) {
                nukeSearch();
            });

        }
    }
}]);
```

Does anyone know why I would be seeing the behavior that I mentioned and am I going about this the wrong way? If so, what is the best approach using Angular 1.2.x and SmartTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I simplified the directive `tndResetSearch` directive above into this:

```
angular.module('app').directive('tndResetSearch', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        require: '^stTable',
        restrict: 'CA',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            var tableCtrl = ctrl,
                fn = $parse(attrs['resetSearch']);

            nukeSearch = function(evt) {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    fn(scope, {
                        $event: evt
                    })
                });
            };

            elem.bind('change', function (evt) {
                nukeSearch(evt);
            });

        }
    }
}]);
```

...and then instead of doing this:

```
$scope.resetSearch = function() {
  delete $scope.searchQuery;
  $scope.initCollection();
}
```

I did this and it works:

```
$scope.resetSearch = function(evt) {
  $scope.initCollection();
  $scope.searchQuery = ' ';
}
```

`searchQuery` is the `ng-model` of my search input box. It seems that it must be anything by an empty string, null or undefined. Otherwise, the stSearch directive does not see a change and assumes that the previous search value is still present.

For what it's worth here is my search text box (in jade):

```
input.form-control(id="serviceLogSearchBox", 
  st-search="{{selectedPredicate}}", placeholder="Search", 
  type="search", ng-model="searchQuery")
```